# I see two 'Stack Overflow' entries under 'Communities' in my profile. Help?

Tags: support, profile-page, communities-list

In my profile, under 'Communities' (right under my avatar), I see two 'Stack Overflow' entries.

[image: two stack overflow entries]

...
However, when I click 'Edit list' to see if I can fix it, I only see one Stack Overflow entry.
...

[image: only one stack overflow entry]

If I 'Hide' this one, it hides both the entries on my main profile.
Can someone help me with removing the second 'Stack Overflow' entry on my profile please? Thanks!

Comment: Weird. Your SO profile links user 5095609 and 5828956. But your [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/3764629/andeart?tab=accounts) links user 5095609 twice!

Answer (score 17):

It looks like you had another account (https://stackoverflow.com/users/5828956/, which doesn't exist anymore) merged into your account. This often breaks the network account list in the sidebar (that list is heavily cached.)

This is almost always fixed when the cache updates itself, which it should within 24 hours. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, it's been longer than 24 hours (possibly more than 48, I lose track of the exact time), and I still see it.

Is it still just a matter of waiting for the SO-cache to update?

Comment: @andeart Worst case, contact the SE staff.

Comment: Caching: [should've known](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)